# Issue with setTimeout in ajax based polling using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my code i need to poll a url after every 5 seconds using ajax . The URL returns a json response. Below is the code that i wrote inside $(document).ready to do this. But,the setTimeout() function does not work. The startPoll() function is called immediately after the response is received.I want to halt for 5 seconds after response is received before calling the startPoll function again . Any way to fix this ?

```
$(document).ready(function(){


   var startPoll = function() {
         $.post('<url>', {},onPollRequestComplete, 'json');

   }

   var onPollRequestComplete = function(response) {

        responseObject = eval(response);

        if(responseObject.success) {
            //Do something here
        }

        setTimeout(startPoll(),5000); /*Make next polling request after 5 seconds*/         

}

startPoll();

});
```

Thank You

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is your problem:

```
setTimeout(startPoll(),5000);
```

You're calling `startPoll` immediately, not after 5 seconds. Instead, you should pass in the function reference, like so:

```
setTimeout(startPoll,5000);
```

If you want the polling to fire every 5 seconds even if previous polls didn't work (a server error was encountered), you should use `setInterval` instead. The code you have now is great if you want to be able to stop polling in case of errors.

Answer (score 1):

I think rather than setTimeout you need to use setInterval

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var startPoll = function() {
                $.post('url', {}, function(response) {
                    var responseObject = eval(response);

                    if (responseObject.success) {
                        alert('hi');
                    }
                }, 'json');
            }

            setInterval(startPoll, 5000); /*Make next polling request after 5 seconds*/

        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Phil.setInterval didnt work either :(

Comment: I think it was your code, I've put an edited version in which works for me now.